# Unable to infer using owl reflexive property with apache jena

Tags: java, rdf, owl, jena

I'm trying to use owl:ReflexiveProperty in an ontology, but I'm not finding the expected inferred statements in the model. I'm currently testing with the following minimal example:

```
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource s = model.getResource(":s");
    Property p = model.getProperty(":p");
    Resource o = model.getResource(":o");
    model.add(s, p, o);
    model.add(p, RDF.type, OWL2.ReflexiveProperty);

    InfModel infModel =
            ModelFactory.createInfModel(ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner(), model);

    System.out.println(infModel.contains(s, p, s));
```

I'm getting false and I'm not sure why.

Comment: reflexivity is not supported by the built-in OWL reasoners as you can see from the docs: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#owl  - the reason is that the OWL support of Jena was mainly build when there was just OWL 1 and reflexivity is an OWL 2 feature   - you would need an external complete OWL DL reasoner like Pellet (via Openllet fork) or try to extend the existing ruleset

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something like that but I couldn't find the source to confirm. My data model is very small, so I'll probably just add the extra statements for now. That resource is very useful because now I think I might be able to use the micro reasoner.